# Facebook Graph API: Get user city (location)

Tags: facebook-graph-api, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have currently implemented facebook login and taking access of user's location. Like this:

```
    user.profile.city = auth.info.location
```

I need only city of user, but location gives city and state. As per permission docs, location is user's city. But it is giving state too.

How to get only city? Is there any way?

Comment: Can you not parse the city out of the `city + state`?

Comment: @Madbreaks don't know how to do that. Sorry m new to ror.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that you are using some `gem` like `omniauth`, `omniauth-facebook`

Try this:

```
 user.profile.city = auth.info.location.split(",")[0]
```

since for example

```
`auth.info.location` value = location: Olongapo City, Philippines
```

using the provided code it will `return Olongapo City`

Comment: This does not work. There are many users with locations that do not include countries. For example, a very popular one is "Liverpool." (real example from real user records). Facebook does not enforce structure on the "location" field - it's a page pointer.

Answer (score 3):

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/

Try with Graph API Explorer : /me
gives the location and home town only with city and state, NOT the zipcode, country, etc.,

```
FB.api('/me', function (json) {
    var fid = json.id;
    var sCity = '';
        var sState = '';
    if (json.location !== undefined && json.location.name !== undefined) {
            var sLoc = json.location.name;
        var aLoc = sLoc.split(',');
        if (aLoc.length > 0) {
            sCity = aLoc[0];
        }
        if (aLoc.length > 1) {
            sState = aLoc[1];
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```
SELECT current_location FROM user WHERE uid=USER_ID
```

Example: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?fql=SELECT%20current_location%20FROM%20user%20WHERE%20uid%3D4